# How to display a process symbol on my page when a command button(update) is clicked?

Tags: visualforce

Here is part of code:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="panelWithVar">
  <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="rowNumber" />
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Case Update">
      <apex:outputPanel >
        <apex:outputLabel value="Case Type : Change" style="font-weight:bold"/>
        <br/><br/>
        <apex:outputLabel value="Case Sub-Type :" style="font-weight:bold" for="type"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <apex:selectList value="{!changeType}" size="1">
          <apex:selectOptions value="{!subTypes}"/>
          <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!caseRecords}" rerender="ajaxRequest,panelWithVar"/>
        </apex:selectList>
      </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  <apex:pageBlock id="thePageblock">
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
      <apex:commandButton value="Update" action="{!Save}"/>
      <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <apex:outputPanel id="ajaxRequest">
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapCaseList}" var="cseWrap" id="table" title="All Cases">
        <apex:column id="theColumnOne">
          <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!cseWrap.selected}" id="inputId" />
        </apex:column>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an apex:actionStatus element, and specify a reRender attribute and a status attribute. Example:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Update" action="{!save}" reRender="" status="updateStatus" />
<apex:actionStatus id="updateStatus">
    <apex:facet name="start">
        <img src="/img/loading32.gif" />
    </apex:facet>
</apex:actionStatus>
```

Comment: It is working..but the processing image is not shown on the center of the page!! @sfdcfox

Comment: You'll want to style this however you like. I personally use a div positioned fixed covering the entire window with the image horizontally and vertically fixed.